# Circle packing: is every optimal arrangement unique?

Tags: circles, packing-problem

For a given shape (e.g. square) and a given number (e.g. 15) of non-overlapping unit circles in the shape, there is an optimal arrangement of the circles that minimizes the area of the shape. [(examples)](http://www.packomania.com/)

Is every optimal arrangement unique? Or is there some shape and some number of circles such that the minimum area of the shape is achieved by different arrangements?

If two arrangements (just considering the circles, not the shape) are mirror images or rotations of each other, I consider them to be the same. Rattlers (circles that can move without causing other circles to move) are not considered when determining if two arrangements are the same.

Comment: Would you be interested in bizarre, unnatural shapes specifically designed to have two distinct optimal circle packings?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Bizarre shapes are acceptable. Incidentally, your question made me realize that I need to further clarify my question. We can consider a shape that is almost like a square, except it has a small dent somewhere. Then for two circles, there is more than one optimal arrangement (the circles can be rotated collectively, relative to the dent). But I would consider these arrangements to be rotations of each other. I will clarify the part of my question about rotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these two non-equivalent optimal packings of $4$ circles in an L-shaped region.

[image]

[image]

You can put in small indentations to prevent "rattlers" from rattling, or instead of the L take the "shape" to be the union of the circles.

[image]

EDIT: Here's an example where the shape is convex.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your idea of small indentations gave me another answer: two unit circles in a 2x5 rectangle with small indentations that can lock the circles in various locations.